# Logstash conditional check for nil/null value in a field

Tags: if-statement, null, logstash

I have a json data with some field value as null (eg: "location": null). I would need to check whether this field is null, and take some action.

I have tried using `if [location] == 'null' { do something }` but it fails, also I have tried with `if [location] == 'nill' { do something }`

Found some relative links that mentioned to check whether the field exist `if [location]` but this can't be used in my case.

Please help me to solve this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `ruby` filter to check if the field has a `null` value.

The following filter checks if the field is null and then, if true, adds a tag to the event.

```
ruby {
    code => "if event.get('location').nil?; event.set('tags','null-value');end"
}
```

You can then use the tag normally in logstash to do what you want, for example

```
if "null-value" in [tags] { do something }
```